# How to spatial subset (clip) TerraSAR-X SSC data (.cos) using vector files and one of the softwares (ENVI, PCI Geomatica, Erdas Imagine, etc)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, software-recommendations, erdas-imagine, envi, geomatica

I have SSC data of San Francisco which I have extracted their extent as a KML file using:

> SARscape > Import Data > SAR Spaceborne > TerraSAR-X

Then through [some operations in ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182194/how-to-find-the-intersection-of-three-polygon-layers-in-arcgis), I have extracted part of these shapefiles and then converted them to (evf/shp):

[image]

Now how can I subset TerraSAR-X data by these vector files using one of the softwares **ENVI**, **PCI Geomatica**, **Erdas Imagine**, **ArcGIS**, etc. without converting the TerraSAR-X image to the internal format of these softwares?

I don't know what should I add to explain more. please ask in the comments any more information you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per ESRI documentation, [List of supported raster and image data formats](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/list-of-supported-raster-and-image-formats.htm#), ArcGIS 10.3 and above support `TerraSAR-X` raster dataset (.cos) although ArcGIS versions below 10.3 may support it too.

[image]

Thus, one further step would be to clip your raster. There are many approaches to achieve this in ArcGIS which can be checked from [Clipping an image or raster in ArcGIS](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/10/05/clipping-imagery-and-raster-data-in-arcgis/)

The simplest would the [Clip (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Clip/00170000009n000000/) with the benefit of automation.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to a question I worked on for subsetting a raster using a shapefile for ERDAS.Please follow the link: [How do I subset image by vector layer using Erdas Imagine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179012/how-do-i-subset-image-by-vector-layer-using-erdas-imagine/181648#181648)

Comment: thanks for the answer. But your question is about a modis image which is a common format for most of the remote sensing softwares. The major problem here is that `.cos` format. I need a software which can show images of this format an can edit the header of such files